# how to add double quotes while printing in json? Currently i am getting single quotes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, faker

code

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(1):
    sds =  {
      "id": "AB-asdfaf",
      "body": fake.sentence(),
      "time": fake.ean(),
      "hash": fake.ean(),
      "id1": fake.ean(),
      "user_id": "asdasdas",
      "id3": "test1"
    }

    print(sds)
```

output i am getting is in single quotes ''. i need to get the json ijn double quotes

output :

```
 'body': 'Throughout third tough will PM time treat.'
```

output i need :

```
"body": "Throughout third tough will PM time treat."
```

Comment: that is only the python representation, you should not worry about that. What is the problem that you have?

Comment: write it in file - you don't have to change quotes.

Comment: ill print some hundreds of random data and post somewhere else. But it ll accept only " "  not ' '

Comment: it doesn't matter - `print()` use single quota to show it on screen but module `json` will write it with double quota.

Comment: tried in jupyter same ' ' are returning

Comment: you don't understand - module `json` will use correct double quota.

Comment: besides, quota is not part of string it is only added when you use `print()` to display list or dictionary. It adds quota to show that you have string `'123'` or number `123`

Comment: avoid answers with .REPLACE!! use json library, json.dumps(dict) to output, and load/loads to input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect correct JSON output, you must convert your data explicitly:

```
 print(json.dumps(sds))
```

It is not only about quotes, `False`, `True` and `None` become `false`, `true` and `null` in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Quota is not part of string and `print()` adds single quota only to show that you have string `'123'` or number `123`

If you use module `json` then you get correctly formated JSON with double quota

```
print( json.dumps(sds) )
```

Full code

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(1):
    sds =  {
      "id": "AB-asdfaf",
      "body": fake.sentence(),
      "time": fake.ean(),
      "hash": fake.ean(),
      "id1": fake.ean(),
      "user_id": "asdasdas",
      "id3": "test1"
    }

    print(json.dumps(sds))
```

Result:

```
{"id": "AB-asdfaf", "body": "Buy government couple.", "time": "6066358112738", "hash": "1204203048039", "id1": "0212772145043", "user_id": "asdasdas", "id3": "test1"}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use:

```
replace('\'', '\"'))
```